# c++ constructor / destructor

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{  
public:
    A ()
    {
        cout<<"cons"<<endl;
    }
    ~A ()
    {
        cout<<"dest"<<endl;
    }
};

A
gokul (void)
{
    A p;

    return p;
}

int
main ()
{
   A a = gokul();
   cout<<"done\n";
}
```

When I run it. I get the following output:

cons

done

dest

I was expecting the output to be:

cons  --> p created,

cons  --> for a, gokul returning

dest  --> p destroyed, gokul returned

done

dest  --> a destroyed, main returned

as the local variable "p" will be destroyed when the function gokul returns and the new variable "a" will be created, no? I have compiled with all three standards 03, 11 & 14 and I get the same result.
~

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: You did not trace the copy constructor.  An object isn't just default constructed, it is also copy constructed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie adding copy constructor with "copy" doesn't change the output

Comment: @BlackMoses -- You must add a copy constructor to correctly trace the output, regardless of the outcome.  Other compilers and or settings could produce different results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code failed to trace the copy constructor.  You need to do this to get a better picture of when an object is created.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{  
public:
    A() { cout<<"cons"<<endl; }
    ~A() { cout<<"dest"<<endl; }
    A(const &A) { cout << "copy constructed" << endl;} 
};

A gokul (void)
{
    A p;
    return p;
}

int main ()
{
   A a = gokul();
   cout<<"done\n";
}
```

When you run this code in Visual Studio 2015, no optimizations, the output is as follows:

```
cons
copy constructed
dest
done
dest
```

When you change to release mode, the output is now this:

```
cons
done
dest
```

The reason for the second output to not have copy construction is due to the `Named Return Value Optimization` that is done to remove the copy.

However the point is that you really can't predict how many times a copy constructor is called.  As you can see, the unoptimized version also works correctly.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. That was good insight! Strangely, I still get the optimized output even after disabling optimization.    g++ -O0  test.cpp

Comment: Well, as stated, you really can't predict these things up front.  Anytime you get the question "how many times is the copy constructor called in this code?", it is a trick question.

Comment: @soupybionics - Yes, this "optimization" is so obvious that g++ is known to perform it even at the `-O0` level. You have to specifically ask it not to, by using `-fno-elide-constructors` if you really want it to produce the large and slow version.

Comment: If you run without optimization `-O0` compiler will use move constructor (C++11). So this code still doesn't track all. Need move constructor to track

Comment: @BoPersson , Thanks. Yes. That flag (along with -O0) worked and I got the following (with c++11 & c++14). The output makes sense to me.                                                                         cons -
copy constructed - 
dest - 
copy constructed -
dest -
done -
dest

Comment: @userbb, Yes. But the output (mentioned above) didn't seem to invoke move. Not sure why.

Comment: @soupybionics But as you can see, with that compiler flag set, the output is still different than Visual Studio.  This goes to show you that you cannot predict what the output will be with things like this.  We now have 3 different outputs from 2 different compilers, and all of the results are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you have optimization turned on then you get this output because of compiler optimization `Copy Elision` [enter link description here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Or if you run your program in debug mode (without optimization), you don't simply trace copy constructor that is used as @PaulMcKenzie explained.

You can try compile without optimization: `/Od` (in visual studio), `-O0` in gcc. Or just run in debug mode. And then back to optimization version by `/O2` or `-O2`.

Beware that from C++11 compiler can use move constructor if you swith to non optimized version `/0d` and still you don't get output. So you need to trace move constructor

```
A(const A&& o){
    cout << "move ctor" << endl;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the OP has optimizations turned on or not?  The original code the OP posted has no copy constructor traced, so we don't know what the output would be if that were inserted.